# iOS App Crashes on Phone but works fine on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have the following code:

```
var displayValue: Double{
    get{
        println("display.text =\(display.text!)")
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set{
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;
    }
}
```

It works fine in the simulator. but when I try it on phone it crashes.
here is the console:

```
digit= 3
display.text =3
operandStack =[3.0]
digit= 2
display.text =2
operandStack =[3.0, 2.0]
display.text =6.0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This line:

NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!

is returning nil which causing the app to crash cause it couldn't unwrap the optional. I really don't know what's wrong. I'm following some tutorials in iTunes U.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because display.text equals nil. That's why it's getting confused.

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq It's not returning nil I printed and it's value is 6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
get{
    println("display.text =\(display.text!)")
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return formatter.numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
}
```

Because, `NSNumberFormatter` uses devices locale by default, it's possible that the decimal separator is not `"."`. For example:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar-SA")
print(formatter.decimalSeparator!) // -> outputs "٫"
formatter.numberFromString("6.0") // -> nil
```

The formatter that uses such locales cannot parse strings like `"6.0"`. So if you want consistent result from the formatter, you should explicitly specify the `locale`.

As for `en_US_POSIX` locale, see [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7):

> In most cases the best locale to choose is `en_US_POSIX`, a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences. `en_US_POSIX` is also invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats dates, `en_US` will change to reflect the new behavior, but `en_US_POSIX` will not), and between platforms (`en_US_POSIX` works the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other platforms).

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Anyway is there a better solution? like to set the locale once and for all ?

Comment: Maybe, you might want to a make singleton class, or global constant that holds cached formatter. But, you should aware that  `NSNumberFormatter` is not thread safe.

Comment: Wow, thanks. What a subtle bug... Only happened on other people's devices, couldn't reproduce, etc. etc.