# Swift: code works on simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I came across this issue when I for the first time tried to run my app on my phone(iPhone 5c, iOS 8.4). It worked fine on the simulator (with iOS 8.4).

```
   var str = "3.8";
    var value = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(str)
    println(value);
```

When i run this code in the simulator it prints "Optional(3.8)". When I run it on my phone it prints: "nil". I find this very odd.

Comment: Very probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382482/ios-app-crashes-on-phone-but-works-fine-on-simulator or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339705/stanford-calculator-app-keeps-crashing (the decimal separator is locale dependent).

Comment: tried with  var str = "3,8" and it worked

Comment: I that case it an issue is the locale. Different in your simulator and your device.